# Why does cin.ignore() act erratically?

Tags: c++

So I've been trying to get my C++ program to "press enter to continue", which I've gathered is an angsty phase every C++ programmer has to go through before reaching adulthood. After fiddling around, I trusted some random advice and used:

```
while(userWins<2)
{
    roundResult = playRound(); 

    if(roundResult>0)
    {
        userWins++;
        cout << "Du vann! Det står nu " << userWins << "-" << cpuWins << "." << endl ;
        cin.get();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
}
```

Which has pretty much the same problem as every other combination of cin.get() and cin.ignore() I've tried - it doesn't do the same thing every time. Sometimes it waits for two enter strokes and sometimes it's okay with one. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Streams are meant for reading/writing a sequence of characters, not for interactive UI. Wrong tool for the job imo.

Comment: What @Cogwheel said. I wish everyone would stop trying to use `STDIN` in this way.

Comment: @Cogwheel if you don't mind what would generally be a better tool for UI than stdin ?

Comment: @A.H. Either a third-party library like curses or using the target platform's console control APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are simply the wrong tool for the job here. The C++ standard doesn't have a portable way to control a console. Streams are an abstraction to allow reading/writing sequences of characters, not for interactive UI.

In order to get the behavior you want reliably, you'll need to use either a third-party library like [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29), or talk directly to your target platform's console APIs.